# Redis Master Slave Switch after Aof rewrite

Tags: redis, master-slave

This Redis Cluster have 240 nodes (120 masters and 120 slaves), and works well for a long time. But now it get a Master Slave switch almost several hours.

I get some log from Redis Server.

```
5c541d3a765e087af7775ba308f51ffb2aa54151
10.12.28.165:6502

13306:M 08 Mar 18:55:02.597 * Background append only file rewriting started by pid 15396
13306:M 08 Mar 18:55:41.636 # Cluster state changed: fail
13306:M 08 Mar 18:55:45.321 # Connection with slave client id #112948 lost.
13306:M 08 Mar 18:55:46.243 # Configuration change detected. Reconfiguring myself as a replica of afb6e012db58bd26a7c96182b04f0a2ba6a45768
13306:S 08 Mar 18:55:47.134 * AOF rewrite child asks to stop sending diffs.
15396:C 08 Mar 18:55:47.134 * Parent agreed to stop sending diffs. Finalizing AOF...
15396:C 08 Mar 18:55:47.134 * Concatenating 0.02 MB of AOF diff received from parent.
15396:C 08 Mar 18:55:47.135 * SYNC append only file rewrite performed
15396:C 08 Mar 18:55:47.186 * AOF rewrite: 4067 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
13306:S 08 Mar 18:55:47.209 # Cluster state changed: ok
```

```
5ac747878f881349aa6a62b179176ddf603e034c
10.12.30.107:6500

22825:M 08 Mar 18:55:30.534 * FAIL message received from da493af5bb3d15fc563961de09567a47787881be about 5c541d3a765e087af7775ba308f51ffb2aa54151
22825:M 08 Mar 18:55:31.440 # Failover auth granted to afb6e012db58bd26a7c96182b04f0a2ba6a45768 for epoch 323
22825:M 08 Mar 18:55:41.587 * Background append only file rewriting started by pid 23628
22825:M 08 Mar 18:56:24.200 # Cluster state changed: fail
22825:M 08 Mar 18:56:30.002 # Connection with slave client id #382416 lost.
22825:M 08 Mar 18:56:30.830 * FAIL message received from 0decbe940c6f4d4330fae5a9c129f1ad4932405d about 5ac747878f881349aa6a62b179176ddf603e034c
22825:M 08 Mar 18:56:30.840 # Failover auth denied to d46f95da06cfcd8ea5eaa15efabff5bd5e99df55: its master is up
22825:M 08 Mar 18:56:30.843 # Configuration change detected. Reconfiguring myself as a replica of d46f95da06cfcd8ea5eaa15efabff5bd5e99df55
22825:S 08 Mar 18:56:31.030 * Clear FAIL state for node 5ac747878f881349aa6a62b179176ddf603e034c: slave is reachable again.
22825:S 08 Mar 18:56:31.030 * Clear FAIL state for node 5c541d3a765e087af7775ba308f51ffb2aa54151: slave is reachable again.
22825:S 08 Mar 18:56:31.294 # Cluster state changed: ok
22825:S 08 Mar 18:56:31.595 * Connecting to MASTER 10.12.30.104:6404
22825:S 08 Mar 18:56:31.671 * MASTER  SLAVE sync started
22825:S 08 Mar 18:56:31.671 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
22825:S 08 Mar 18:56:31.672 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
22825:S 08 Mar 18:56:31.673 * Partial resynchronization not possible (no cached master)
22825:S 08 Mar 18:56:31.691 * AOF rewrite child asks to stop sending diffs.
```

It appends that Redis Master Slave Swtich happend after Aof rewtiting.

Here is the config of this cluster.

```
daemonize no
tcp-backlog 511
timeout 0
tcp-keepalive 60
loglevel notice
databases 16
dir "/var/cachecloud/data"
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no
repl-timeout 60
repl-ping-slave-period 10
repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no
repl-backlog-size 10000000
repl-backlog-ttl 7200
slave-serve-stale-data yes
slave-read-only yes
slave-priority 100
lua-time-limit 5000
slowlog-log-slower-than 10000
slowlog-max-len 128
hash-max-ziplist-entries 512
hash-max-ziplist-value 64
list-max-ziplist-entries 512
list-max-ziplist-value 64
set-max-intset-entries 512
zset-max-ziplist-entries 128
zset-max-ziplist-value 64
activerehashing yes
client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
client-output-buffer-limit slave 512mb 128mb 60
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60
hz 10
port 6401
maxmemory 13000mb
maxmemory-policy volatile-lru
appendonly yes
appendfsync no
appendfilename "appendonly-6401.aof"
dbfilename "dump-6401.rdb"
aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite yes
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 62500kb
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 86
rdbcompression yes
rdbchecksum yes
repl-diskless-sync no
repl-diskless-sync-delay 5
maxclients 10000
hll-sparse-max-bytes 3000
min-slaves-to-write 0
min-slaves-max-lag 10
aof-load-truncated yes
notify-keyspace-events ""
bind 10.12.26.226
protected-mode no
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-node-timeout 15000
cluster-slave-validity-factor 10
cluster-migration-barrier 1
cluster-config-file "nodes-6401.conf"
cluster-require-full-coverage no
rename-command FLUSHDB ""
rename-command FLUSHALL ""
rename-command KEYS ""
```

In my option, aof rewrite will not effect the Redis Main Thread. BUT this seems make this node not response other nodes' Ping.

Answer (score 0):

Check THP(Transparent Huge pages) on Linux kernel parameter.
because AOF diff size 0.02MB, copy-on-write size 2067MB.